# Split an expression to float numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this `"2/-4+5.7*5*-7.9+3"`
I want to split it in an array such that the elements are the absolute value of floating numbers only `[2,4,5.7,5,7.9,3]`

Comment: I tried [\\D+] but it splits by the non numeric characters even the decimal point

Comment: Try `[^\\d.]`, the `^` makes it the negative.

Comment: For future question you might want to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (it's always good to post what you did try, some code, ...)

Answer (score 2):

You could try matching instead of splitting.

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jA7pT6/1)

Spitting the string according to one or more operators (*`-`,`*`,`/`,`+`*) will give you the desired output.

```
String test = "2/-4+5.7*5*-7.9+3";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split("[-/+*]+")));
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 5.7, 5, 7.9, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String s = "2/-4+5.7*5*-7.9+3";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?[0-9]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;

        while ( m.find() ) {
            n1++;
        }

        float[] array = new float[n1];

        while ( m.find() && n2 <= n1) {
            array[n2] = Float.parseFloat(s.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
            n2++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"2/-4+5.7*5*-7.9+3".split(/[\/\-\+\*]{1,}/)
```

result: ["2", "4", "5.7", "5", "7.9", "3"]

additionally you have to parseFloat() each item to get numeric values